# change color when tr in table is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which is conected with mysql database. I need to change color when every cell in tr is full. Can you suggest me the best way to solve this?

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
 <tr>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Slika</th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Ime producta </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Kategorija </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Zemun </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Balkanska </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Novi Sad </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Bulevar </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Piramida </th>
     <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Datum dodavanja</th>
 </tr>
   </thead>

  <tbody>

 <?php foreach ($products as $product):?>

   <tr>          
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['image']); ?></td>             
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['name']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['categorie']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['zemun']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['balkanska']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['novi_sad']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['bulevar']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo remove_junk($product['piramida']); ?></td>
<td> <?php echo read_date($product['date']); ?></td>
   </tr>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean full? and what `remove_junk`, do

Comment: In the moment when every cell in td is filled, I want to change background color of the whole row. So when the value is entered in all fields (Zemun, Balkanska, Novi Sad, Bulevar, Piramida)

Comment: `<td style="<?php isset($product['array_key_here']) ? 'color:red' : '' ?> > <?php echo remove_junk($product['image']); ?></td>` use same code for each `td`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a css class name for when all data is present for a row like this...

PHP:

```
$showColor = "";

if(!empty($product['image']) && !empty($product['name']) &&
     !empty($product['categorie']) && !empty($product['zemun']) &&
     !empty($product['balkanska']) && !empty($product['novi_sad']) &&
     !empty($product['bulevar']) && !empty($product['piramida']) &&
     !empty($product['date'])) {
         $showColor = "show_color";
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr class="<?php echo $showColor; ?>">
    ...
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.show_color { background: blue } // whatever color you want
```

Comment: Incredibly, it is opposite. Every empty cell is blue, but not filled. how can I make opposite of this code? so, only filled rows to be blue.

Comment: try changing all the `isset()` to `!empty()` for the product values